# Use of radiolarian fossils to assess CO2 levels in early geological periods

Tags: oceanography, rocks

Radiolaria are microscopic marine protozoans commonly found as fossils in rocks dating as far back as the early Cambrian. Their silica skeletons are damaged by high levels of CO2, so is it possible to use this damage to assess the CO2 levels present at the time when the dead radiolarians sank into the ooze on the ocean floor?